# Cannot Inflate SpinnerView After Screen Rotation

Tags: android, spinner

the title explaines the problem..

in manifest i added

```
    android:configChanges="locale|orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

to the activity

and in the oncreate method

```
    spinnerView = (Spinner) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.spinner_layout, null);    ///becomes null when screen rotates!
```

....rest of code

it all working and fine. But when i rotate the screen the spinner disappears (and i get nullpointer exception)but everything else seems fine. please help

spinner layout:

```
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:entries="@array/spinner_items"
/>
```

I tried Making a Spinner Programatically Like this:

In onCreate:

```
Spinner spinnerView=new Spinner(TaskListAndOptionsActivity.activityContext);
 String[] strings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner_items);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activityContext,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,strings);
   adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   spinnerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But the same thing is happening on screen rotate.

Comment: Does it appear when you rotate it back?

Comment: No, but if i go to another activity and back to this one, it works again(until i rotate the screen)

Comment: Are you using different layouts files for normal and landscape mode?

Comment: Yes but they both have the same code for this layout

Comment: i tried adding the spinnerView to onConfigurationChanged method but also the same thing. i get an error nullpointer exception

Comment: But onCreate will not be called again since you added orientation and screenSize in configChanges.

Comment: Yes i know, but this should not make the spinnerView disappear should it?. Everything else remains the same except this.

Comment: Strange. Should work for things you posted, sure your not changing the visibility somewhere in code?

Comment: no:/. But I even Tried To Make A Spinner Programatically and the same thing happened. ill post the code if that helps